# Prolog: get the solution with minimal absolute value from the list of solutions

Tags: prolog

Suppose, we have the following equation in Z_{12} we want to solve in Prolog:

(x + y) mod 12 = z

with the following domains for variables:

- x \in [0, 11]
- y \in [-11, 11]
- z \in [0, 11]

We write the following predicate:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

solve(X, Y, Z) :-
    X #> -1,
    X #< 12,
    Y #> -12,
    Y #< 12,
    Z #> -1,
    Z #< 12,
    Z #= mod(X + Y, 12).
```

Then we try to solve the equation: (11 + y) mod 12 = 1

```
?- solve(11, Y, 1).
Y in -10..2,
11+Y#=_A,
_A in 1..13,
_A mod 12#=1.
```

Prolog says that there are 2 solutions: {-10, 2}, which is true:

**1** 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 (<-) **11** (->) 0 **1**

To reach 1 from 11 we can move ether 10 steps backwards and 2 steps forward.

Question: how get the the solution with minimal absolute value? So having {-10, 2} take 2 from it.
If we have {-2, 10} take -2.

If the values are equal by the absolute value, take both of them: {-6, 6}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Prolog says that there are 2 solutions: {-10, 2}, which is true:

That `-10..2` is a range telling you the solutions are bounded at -10 and 2, but could be any of the values in between. Exactly two solutions would look like `-10\/2`. You need to *label* Y for it to search for the answers.

> The order of solutions can be influenced with:

```
min(Expr)
max(Expr)
```

- https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=labeling%2f2

So you can get the smallest absolute value first using that, e.g.:

```
?- solve(11,Y,1),
   labeling([min], [Y]).

Y = -10

?- solve(11,Y,1),
   labeling([min(abs(Y))], [Y]).

Y = 2
```

But to do the test if they are equal you might need something like finding both values for Y (assuming there are always two) and if/else branching on the result, but this is a bit ugly:

```
solve(11,Y,1), 
findall(Y, 
        labeling([min(abs(Y))], [Y]), 
        [Y1, Y2]),

(Y1 = Y2
    -> Answer = Y1-Y2
    ;  Answer = Y1)
.
```